# RESTful API parsing DBF data HSET in Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, redis

I have this working code, but would like your review:

sync.coffe

```
path = require "path"
Promise = require "bluebird"
DBFParser = require "node-dbf"
request = require "request"
config = require "config"
zlib = require "zlib"

gzipPr = Promise.promisify zlib.gzip, zlib
postPr = Promise.promisify request.post, request

parseAccountRecord = (dbfr) ->
  # SNAME.SN_DORMANT = record no longer active - we don't care
  if dbfr['@deleted'] or dbfr.SN_DORMANT is "T" then return null
  {
    # Account meta
    snAccount: dbfr.SN_ACCOUNT
    snStop: dbfr.SN_STOP
    snTprfl: dbfr.SN_TPRFL #
    snCprfl: dbfr.SN_CPRFL
    snCustype: dbfr.SN_CUSTYPE
    snTerrtry: dbfr.SN_TERRTRY
    # Account invoice details
    snVat: dbfr.SN_VRN
    snContact: dbfr.SN_CONTACT
    snEmail: dbfr.SN_EMAIL
    snName: dbfr.SN_NAME 
    snAddr1: dbfr.SN_ADDR1
    snAddr2: dbfr.SN_ADDR2
    snAddr3: dbfr.SN_ADDR3
    snAddr4: dbfr.SN_ADDR4
    snPstcode: dbfr.SN_PSTCODE
    snCtry: dbfr.SN_CTRY
    snTelno: dbfr.SN_TELENO
    snWwwpage: dbfr.SN_WWWPAGE
  }

filesInfo = 
  "c_sname.dbf" : [ parseAccountRecord, "account"]

uploadRecords = (records, endPoint) ->
  url = config.webapp.baseUrl + "/api/" + endPoint
  process.stdout.write "...Pushing #{records.length} #{endPoint} to #{url}, "
  gzipPr new Buffer(JSON.stringify(records))
    .then (gzbuf) ->
      postOptions =
        url: url
        body: gzbuf
        headers:
          "Content-type": "application/json"
          "Content-Encoding": "gzip"
          "Content-Length": gzbuf.length
      postPr postOptions
    .spread (response, body) ->
      console.log "pushed", body

parseNPush = (basename, parseFunc, apiEndPoint) ->
  console.log ">>>"
  console.log "   ...parsing #{basename}"
  fullPath = path.join config.opera.dataDir , basename
  parseDBFFile( fullPath, parseFunc )
    .then( (records) -> uploadRecords(records, apiEndPoint) )
    .catch( (err) -> console.error(err) )

onFileChanged = (fname) ->
  fname = path.basename fname
  fInfo = filesInfo[fname]
  if not fInfo then return 
  parseNPush fname, fInfo[0], fInfo[1]

parseAll = ->
  Promise.map Object.keys(filesInfo), onFileChanged, {concurrency: 1}
    .then -> 
      console.log "All records parsed -- Done, re-load in 60s..."
      setTimeout parseAll, config.parseInterval
```

then on the node.js application I have

api.coffee

```
express = require "express"
filters = require "../filters"
_ = require "lodash"
config = require "config"
redisClient = require("redis-url").connect(config.database.redis.url)
Promise = require "bluebird"
hmsetPr = Promise.promisify redisClient.hmset, redisClient

exports.router = () ->
  express.Router()
    .post "/account", account
    .use (req,res) -> res.status(404).send("Invalid API Call")

account = (req, res, next) ->
  snProfileMap = _(req.body).map( (r) ->
    profileMap = {
      snAccount: r.snAccount
      snStop: r.snStop
      snTprfl: r.snTprfl
      snCprfl: r.snCprfl
      snCustype: r.snCustype
      snTerrtry: r.snTerrtry
    }
    [r.snAccount, JSON.stringify(profileMap)] ).zipObject().value()
  snInvoiceMap = _(req.body).map( (r) ->
    invoiceMap = {
      snAccount: r.snAccount
      snVat: r.snVat
      snContact: r.snContact
      snEmail: r.snEmail
      snName: r.snName
      snAddr1: r.snAddr1
      snAddr2: r.snAddr2
      snAddr3: r.snAddr3
      snAddr4: r.snAddr4
      snPstcode: r.snPstcode
      snCtry: r.snCtry
      snTelno: r.snTelno
      snWwwpage: r.snWwwpage
    }
    [r.snAccount, JSON.stringify(invoiceMap)] ).zipObject().value()  
  hmsetPr "profile", snProfileMap
  hmsetPr "invoice", snInvoiceMap
    .then (result) -> res.status(200).send("Ok")
    .catch next
```

Basically, I am sending one large json file, this is then split into two parts and stored each part inside a different Redis set, so in this case `profile` and `invoice`

Is there a better way to re-write `sync.coffee`, keeping in mind that the JSON file will grow over time?

I was thinking of parsing the record twice, but it does not make sense as this is done already and sending it to two different end-points!

Any advice much appreciated